# Sequences and Series - Find the value of n for which...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am having some difficulty trying to solve this question.

I have been given this question - 
 Find the correct value of the letter n for which `Xn = 5n - 2` and `Xn = 153`

I have done trial and error to give the result of 31 but isn't there a more mechanical way of solving this using algebra?

Thanks,  Bob.

Comment: Sure, $5n-2=153$ so $5n=155$ so $n=155/5=31$.

Comment: Given $X_{n} = 153$ and $X_{n} = 5n-2\;,$ Put value of $X_{n}\;,$ We get $153=5n-2\Rightarrow 5n = 155\Rightarrow n= 31$

Comment: By the way, congratulations on the trial and error. You went after the answer in a serious way.

Answer (score 1):

$5n-2=153$ is the equation we have to solve which is equivalent to $5n=155$ therefore $n=31$.

Answer (score 0):

So we have a sequence $X_n=5n-2$
And you know that $153 =X_n$ for some n.
Which means that 153=5n-2 for some n.
And solving the equation:
153=5n-2-->155=5n-->n=31